# i need a way to toggle between two div containers with a animate of width

Tags: jquery, html

I have two div containers with content in them and two buttons outside the container like so:

```
<div id="containers">
    <div id="container_1">
        awesome container 1 content
    </div>
    <div id="container_2">
        awesome container 2 content
    </div>
</div>

<div id="container_1_button">
    Click me to open container 1
</div>
<div id="container_2_button">
    Click me to open container 2
</div>
```

I need to be able to animate width and left: to give the effect of the content sliding from the left when clicked. But only one can be open at a time. psuedo code would be: `IE: if Container 1 width  > 0 set width:0, set left:0` and the same for container 2. So that way if someone clicks on button 2 while container 1 is open it collapses container 1 and then opens container 2 and vice versa.

I have achieve the animation of the width/left pos on one element by using the following jquery:

```
//the Jquery collapsible left hand sidebarfor mapit
$('#map_sidebar_button').toggle(function(){
    collapseSidebarLeft();
    $('#sidebar_left_map').animate({width:0}, 'fast');
    $('.button_container').animate({left:0}, 'fast');
    $('#map_sidebar_button').removeClass('sidebar_left_button_toggle');
},function(){
    $('#sidebar_left_map').animate({width:260}, 'fast');
    $('.button_container').animate({left:260}, 'fast');
        // add a class to change the background coloring and border of the button
    $('#map_sidebar_button').addClass('sidebar_left_button_toggle');
});
```

You can see an example of the site that i need this implemented on here: 
http://demo.mapitusa.com the left sidebar buttons..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to use the `.each()` method and bind a (single) `click` to each button with the same `class`, and depending on which one you clicked (based on its *index*) then select what **awesome container** to display.

In this scenario, both **awesome containers** would have the same `class` too and will be hidden from visibility using a negative margin of the same value of their `width`, why? because in this way they won't show the weird effect produced while animating the `width` (the elements inside the container will look like floating and arranging themselves during the animation) ... so using this html:

```
<div id="containers">
 <div id="container_1" class="awesome">awesome container 1 content</div>
 <div id="container_1_button" class="buttonsContainer"><a class="button" href="javascript:;">open 1</a></div>
 <div class="clear"></div><!--used in my example to separate floating containers-->
 <div id="container_2" class="awesome">awesome container 2 content</div>
 <div id="container_2_button" class="buttonsContainer"><a class="button" href="javascript:;">open 2</a></div>
</div>
```

the css for both containers and parent

```
#containers {
 position: relative;
}
#containers .awesome {
 width: 300px; /* or whatever */
 margin-left: -300px; /* negative value of the width */
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left; /* to illustrate my example */
 display: block; /* if needed */
 /* etc other container properties */
}
```

then the jQuery where we assign a single `click` to the same selector (the shared `class` of both buttons)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".button").each(function(i){
  var selector = $(this); // useful to refer to 'this' inside of any nested function
  selector.on("click", function(){
   if($(".awesome").eq(i).hasClass('visible')){
    $(".awesome").eq(i).animate({'marginLeft':-300},{ queue:false, duration: 200}).removeClass('visible');
   } else {
    // collapse all if any
    $(".awesome").animate({'marginLeft': -300},{ queue:false, duration:200, complete: function(){
      // remove to all the class "visible" if any
      $(".awesome")
       .removeClass('visible')
       // animate the corresponding (i) container and add class="visible"
       .eq(i).animate({'marginLeft':0},{ queue:false, duration:600})
       .addClass('visible');
     } // complete
    }); // animate
   } // if else
  }); //on
 }); //each
}); //ready
```

Notice that we use the `complete` callback option of `.animate()` so the next animation will be executed until the first one has been completed, in this case the second container will show up only until the first one collapses.

You can [see it working here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/toggleTwoContainers_28mar12.html) for better understanding of the effect.

Comment: does that mean I got the bounty? ;)

Comment: Hey JFK, do you have AIM, MSN, gchat, skype? I have some questions about implementing this code. having issues getting the css down pact.

Comment: I dropped you a message at gorelative[dot]com with my email address

Answer (score 1):

Since `div` elements are `display : block` by default we need to change their `display` property so they will sit next to each other instead of being on their own lines. `display : inline-block` will do the trick, but be aware that for IE7 you need this hack: `*display : inline; zoom : 1;`. Also, the `overflow : hidden` is important so the content will be hidden when animating the slide.

JS --

```
$(function () {
    $('#container_1_button').on('click', function () {

        //button 1 was clicked so animate container_1 into view
        $('#container_1').stop().animate({
            width : 200
        }, 1000);

        //animate container_2 out of view
        $('#container_2').stop().animate({
            width : 0
        }, 1000);
    });
    $('#container_2_button').on('click', function () {

        //animate container_2 into view
        $('#container_2').stop().animate({
            width : 200
        }, 1000);

        //animate container_1 out of view
        $('#container_1').stop().animate({
            width : 0
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

CSS --

```
#containers div {
    display  : inline-block;
    position : relative;
    overflow : hidden;
    height   : 40px;
}
#container_1 {
    width : 200px;
}
#container_2 {
    width : 0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RBmLt/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.

Comment: thanks that code looks great... i need it to toggle between though.. something similair to using toggle()

Comment: i updated my original post with a link to my demo site where you can see i need to implement this

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. At the moment if you click the `1` button, then the `1` content is shown, and the same goes for the `2` button. What else would you like?

Comment: need to be able to toggle between the two.. they both start out closed.. `1` is clicked, collapse `2` if its open, open `1`, click `1` again.. collapse `1`, click `2` while `1` is open and collapse `1` and open `2`..

Comment: Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/RBmLt/2/. I also consolidated the code into a single event handler that deals with all the buttons/containers.

Comment: this is great, however i need them both to slide in/out from left. The div is a sidebar menu that slides over a map canvas. in and out, some very remedial code is here, got most of it functioning but when i click events it opens both. http://jsfiddle.net/8Hze2/10/

Comment: adding a bounty to this to get a better answer. Edited my answer to include a demo URL to see the sidebar sliding in action with a single div element.